# NullPointerException при вызове Toast в другом классе. (не активити)

Tags: java, android, activity, методы, android-toast

Есть 2 класса.

Первый:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FirstClass extends AppCompatActivity
{
    SecondClass mSecondClass; //объявляется второй класс
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_class);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); //кнопка и обработчик для неё
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                mSecondClass.methodToast(); //вызывается метод из другого класса
            }
        });
    }
}
```

И второй:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondClass extends Activity
{
    public void methodToast() {
        Toast.makeText(SecondClass.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку возникает ошибка: `java.lang.NullPointerException`, а в LogCat указывается проблемный участок: `mSecondClass.methodToast();`. То есть возникают проблемы при вызове метода.

Подскажите, где я ошибся и как правильно следует вызывать методы из другого класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй класс не должен расширять класс активити. Если вам нужно в нём вызвать `Toast`, то вам надо передать туда `Context` текущей активити. Например через конструктор.

```
public class SecondClass
{
    Context ctx;

    public SecondClass(Context ctx) { this.ctx = ctx; }

    public void methodToast() {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Теперь в основной активити вам надо создать экземпляр класса, передать через конструктор `Context` и только потом вызывать метод.

```
mSecondClass = new SecondClass(FirstClass.this);
mSecondClass.methodToast();
```

---

либо модифицировать метод, задав ему `Context` в качестве аргумента:

```
public class SecondClass
{

    public SecondClass() {}

    public void methodToast(Context ctx) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Вызывать надо тоже только после создания экземпляра класса

```
mSecondClass = new SecondClass();
mSecondClass.methodToast(FirstClass.this);
```

---

А ещё можно метод сделать статическим. тогда экземпляр класса создавать не придётся:

```
public class SecondClass
{    
    public static void methodToast(Context ctx) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Вызвать можно будет так:

```
SecondClass.methodToast(FirstClass.this);
```

Comment: От всей души спасибо за разъяснения. А каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "назад" (метод onBackPressed, вызываемый в первом классе) выполнялся метод из класса, который наследуется от ListFragment? То есть SecondClass наследуется не от Activity, а от ListFragment. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: @Win_D, можно, например, через `FragmentManager` найти фрагмент и вызвать его метод. Если сразу не выйдет - создавайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Боюсь, что не выйдет, т. к. у меня в ListFragment не используются другие фрагменты (только ArrayAdapter, которые меняются при нажатии на пункт). В любом случае, спасибо за помощь, попробую самостоятельно по изучать.

Comment: Ваш ListFragment точно можно найти через мэнеджер. Что в нём происходит - не важно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, взгляните на этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481722/nullpointerexception-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-listfragment

Answer (score 2):

Как ответил ЮрийСПб,
У вас во втором классе не хватает контекста, поэтому необходимо создать обьект второго класса и передать ему в конструктор контекст первого класса. 
Тогда это не будет вызывать исключение.
Надеюсь мой совет поможет Вам.

Это можно сделать примерно так

В первом классе в обработчике нажатия кнопки пишем

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
      new SecondClass(FirstClass.this).methodToast(); // здесь создается сразу обьект второго класса и вызывается метод из другого класса
}
```

во втором классе создаете конструктор с контекстом,

Answer (score 0):

У вас не инициализирован mSecondClass.
Например:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.doSomething();
```

Comment: Не сработает. точнее решит текущую ошибку, но приведёт к другой из-за нужды `Toast.makeText` в `Context`, коего не будет в классе-активити, коя не отображается.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, вам нужно создать объект класса.

```
SecondClass mSecondClass = new SecondClass ();
```

И создать конструктор во втором классе

```
SecondClass() {}
```

Comment: Не сработает. точнее решит текущую ошибку, но приведёт к другой из-за нужды `Toast.makeText` в `Context`, коего не будет в классе-активити, коя не отображается.