# NullPointerException при вызове метода из ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть основной класс MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    List list = new List(); //объявление второго класса (наследующего ListFragment)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
       list.enterBackButton(); //передача действий в другой метод
    }
}
```

И дополнительный, в котором обрабатываются все операции:

```
public class List extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
{
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1, adapter2, adapter3;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test1));
        setListAdapter(adapter1);
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if (getListAdapter() == adapter1)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test2));
                    setListAdapter(adapter2);
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (getListAdapter() == adapter2)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test3));
                    setListAdapter(adapter3);
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void enterBackButton () //объявление нового метода
    {
        if (getListAdapter() == adapter2)
        {
            setListAdapter(adapter1);
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else if (getListAdapter() == adapter3)
        {
            setListAdapter(adapter2);
            adapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "назад" выполнялся не стандартный метод `onBackPressed`, а происходила передача действия в метод `enterBackButton`, который выполнял нужные операции. Однако при нажатии кнопки "назад" вылезает ошибка `java.lang.NullPointerException` и даёт ссылку на проблемные участки:

```
list.enterBackButton(); //функция находится в классе MainActivity
adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged(); //функция из класса List
```

Помогите разобраться избавиться от проблемы, т. е. чтобы при нажатии кнопки "назад" нормально вызывался метод из другого класса и выполнял необходимые действия.

Comment: Если фрагмент у вас в разметке активити, то удалите его оттуда и добавляйте в разметку программно. После чего находите через ФрагментМэнеджер и вызывайте его методы.

Comment: Код активити, который вы предоставили, это весь код или же фрагмент все таки где-то добавляется в активити, но вы просто вырезали данный код из вопроса?

Comment: @temq фрагмент добавляется к активити статично в xml-разметке через тег <fragment>

Comment: `adapter2` у вас на момент вызова `enterBackButton` не инициализирован, вы в него ничего не записали.

Comment: Ну поэтому у вас и ошибка, т.к. тот что отображается это один экземпляр фрагмента, а тот что вы создали в активити это другой, в котором ни один из адаптеров не инициализирован, но в котором вы вызываете метод ```enterBackButton ```. Добавляете фрагмент программно, либо ищите его по ```id```.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

У вас создаётся экземпляр класса `ArrayAdapter` для переменной `adapter1`:

```
    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), 
                                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                              getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test1));
```

Но создание объекта для `adapter2` только тут:

```
 adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), 
                                           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                           getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test2));
```

Вы вызываете `enterBackButton ()` до того, как инициализировали `adapter2`. Вот и выпадает `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Как верно заметили в комментариях, вы создала фрагмент, но не прикрепили его к `Activity`, у вас даже `onActivityCreated` не вызовется, следовательно и в `adapter1` будет `null`.

Comment: ТС вообще не добавил фрагмент в активити. Он лишь создал его экземпляр. И, в итоге, все поля класса фрагмента - `null`. В т.ч. и адаптер, коий кидает `NPE`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб и это тоже)

Comment: Всё у ТС печально)

Answer (score 1):

Вы создали экземпляр класса, расширяющего `Fragment` но не добавили его в активити. Засим не были вызваны методы его жизненного цикла. Из-за этого адаптер не инициализирован и, в итоге, он равен `null`. От этого у вас `NPE`.

**Решение:**

добавьте фрагмент в активити.
Если фрагмент у вас в разметке активити, то удалите его оттуда и добавляйте в разметку программно. После чего находите через ФрагментМэнеджер и вызывайте его методы.